# Exception in thread "weblogic.transaction.TxTimer: '1'

Tags: java, exception, transactions, weblogic, out-of-memory

I'm useing intellij 9 with weblogic that i get folowing exception. I did increase the memory to `-Xmx512g` also but still hase the same exception. What should be the reason?

```
Exception in thread "weblogic.transaction.TxTimer: '1'" 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: It was memory leak in my code.I did change code, now everything is ok.

Comment: which was the code that produced the memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was memory leak in my code.I did change code, now everything is ok.